# Script that finds and deletes files older than 2014

Tags: find, date

I am trying to write a script that finds files that are from before September 24th, 2014, and deletes them. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a dummy file with time set to Sept. 24 2014 00:00h, then find anything NOT newer and delete:

```bash
#date format YYYYMMDDhhmm
touch -t 201409240000 dateref
find -type f ! -newer dateref -delete
```

Please make yourself a bit familiar with `find` before using the `-delete` option. Note that is must be on the last position and maybe check the results without `-delete` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

d2=$(date +%s)
d1=$(date -d "2014-09-24" +%s)
d=$(( (d2 - d1) / 86400 ))

find ./ -mtime +$d -delete
```

First, try it without `-delete` to make sure that the right files are found. When you are 100% sure add `-delete`. And use your desired path instead of `./` in find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`'s  `-newer` option with (a reference file which has that date), along with `!` to negate the -newer.  You can use `touch -d` to create the reference file. For example:

```bsh
touch -d "2014-09-23 23:59:59.999999999" /tmp/reference-file
find /path/to/directory/ ! -newer /tmp/reference-file -ls
```

You will probably want to pipe that into `less` or redirect to a file for examination.

Change the `-ls` option to `-delete` after you've confirmed that it will only delete files you want deleted.

(if you don't mind also deleting files that were created exactly at midnight on 2014-09-14, you can just use `touch -d 2014-09-24` - because `! -newer` doesn't just mean "older than", it means "older than or equal to".  The .999999999 is probably "good enough" for most purposes)

Note: the above assumes GNU versions of both `find` and `touch`.  May or may not work with other versions.   If you're using Linux, GNU utils are standard (unless you're using some tiny distro that uses `busybox` or similar to save space).

From `man find`:

> `-newer reference`
>
> Time of the last data modification of the current file is
> more recent than that of the last data modification of the
> reference file.  If reference is a symbolic link and the
> `-H` option or the `-L` option is in effect, then the time
> of the last data modification of the file it points to is
> always used.

See also `-anewer` in the same man page if you want to use access times rather than modification time.

The `-newerXY` options are also relevant:

> -newerXY reference
>
> Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is
> newer than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters X
> and Y can be any of the following letters:
>
> ```
>  a   The access time of the file reference
>  B   The birth time of the file reference
>  c   The inode status change time of reference
>  m   The modification time of the file reference
>  t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
> ```
>
> Some combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid
> for `X` to be `t`.  Some combinations are not implemented
> on all systems; for example `B` is not supported on all
> systems.
> If an invalid or unsupported combination of `XY` is
> specified, a fatal error results.
>
> Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to
> the `-d` option of GNU `date`.
>
> If you try to use the birth time of a reference file, and
> the birth time cannot be determined, a fatal error message
> results.
>
> If you specify a test which refers to the birth time of
> files being examined, this test will fail for any files
> where the birth time is unknown.

Comment: Note that there's nothing GNU-specific in `find /path/to/directory/ ! -newer /tmp/reference-file -ls`. `-ls` is not standard but is a common extension originally from SysV IIRC.  `! -newermt 2014-09-24` is not POSIX but is from BSD, not a GNU extension either. `touch -d` is POSIX though you'd need `2014-09-13T23:59:59.999999999`. Using `touch -t` is more portable.

Comment: That's why I said "**May or may not work with other versions**".  I don't care enough about non-GNU versions to put in the time and effort to find out.  It's there only as a warning to the OP and other readers that it's non-standard and may not work on their system if it's some ancient or proprietary unix/unix-like system.